# @synchronized not working in MRC,my app crash in multithreaded

Tags: ios, multithreading, automatic-ref-counting, synchronized

```
//person.h
@interface Person : NSObject

@property(retain, nonatomic) NSString *indexStr;

- (instancetype)initWithIndex:(int)index;

- (void)print;

@end

//person.m
@implementation Person

- (instancetype)initWithIndex:(int)index
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _indexStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",index];
        NSLog(@"person init index:%d",index);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    self.indexStr = nil;
    NSLog(@"person dealloc index:%@",self.indexStr);
    [super dealloc];
}

@end    

//vc.h
@property (retain, nonatomic) Person *person;

//vc.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _person = [[Person alloc] initWithIndex:-1];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [self actionWrite:@(i)];
        });
    }

    //    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(actionRead) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void)actionWrite:(NSNumber *)num
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        self.person = [[[Person alloc] initWithIndex:[num intValue]] autorelease];
    }
}
```

## The code is in MRC.

It will crash at "actionWrith:" method. The log is:

```
2014-09-16 10:11:26.452 testThreadNoARC[1777:149948] person init index:357
2014-09-16 10:11:26.452 testThreadNoARC[1777:149961] person init index:358
2014-09-16 10:11:26.452 testThreadNoARC[1777:149947] person init index:359
2014-09-16 10:11:26.452 testThreadNoARC[1777:149937] person init index:360
2014-09-16 10:11:26.452 testThreadNoARC[1777:149944] person init index:361
2014-09-16 10:11:26.452 testThreadNoARC[1777:149950] person init index:362
2014-09-16 10:11:26.452 testThreadNoARC[1777:149941] person init index:363
2014-09-16 10:11:26.452 testThreadNoARC[1777:149959] person init index:364
2014-09-16 10:11:26.452 testThreadNoARC[1777:149955] person init index:365
2014-09-16 10:11:26.452 testThreadNoARC[1777:149951] person init index:366
2014-09-16 10:11:26.452 testThreadNoARC[1777:149958] person init index:367
2014-09-16 10:11:26.466 testThreadNoARC[1777:149975] person init index:368
2014-09-16 10:11:26.466 testThreadNoARC[1777:149964] person init index:369
2014-09-16 10:11:26.466 testThreadNoARC[1777:149971] person init index:370
2014-09-16 10:11:26.466 testThreadNoARC[1777:149863] *** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fdc5bec77b0
```

It crashed at thread 1 everytime, I don't know why this will happyen.
I think the Person object has been released, there maybe release again to make the crash.
but everytime I run the code, it's crash log is the same.
The same code run well at ARC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this line in your `Person` initializer:

```
    _indexStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",index];
```

The `stringWithFormat:` message returns an autoreleased value.  You're storing it directly to the instance variable managed by a `retain` property.  Since you bypassed the setter, the setter didn't get a chance to retain it.  As soon as the autorelease pool is drained, the string will be released.  Since you never retained it, the system deallocates it.  Now `_indexStr` is a dangling pointer.

Later, in `-[Person dealloc]`, you do this:

```
self.indexStr = nil;
```

Since `indexStr` is a `retain` property, its setter looks like this:

```
- (void)setIndexStr:(NSString *)value {
    NSString *oldValue = _indexStr;
    [value retain];
    _indexStr = value;
    [oldValue release];
}
```

This means that when the setter does `[oldValue release]`, it sends `release` to that dangling pointer.  This is where you crash.

The best thing to do is **stop using MRC** and **start using ARC**.

Under MRC, you can retain the string correctly in your `Person` initializer in several ways.  Any of these will do:

```
    _indexStr = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",index] retain];

    // or

    self.indexStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",index]

    // or

    _indexStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", index];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not retaining the string used for `_indexStr`. Change:

```
_indexStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",index];
```

to:

```
_indexStr = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",index] retain];
```